# Access FTP files from java without filezilla or winscp

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have made java web application for uploading file in ftp and in the same application user can directly open files in browser. It is running successfully when Filezilla or winscp is opened. After closing filezilla and winscp I can't access or upload files to ftp. Is there any possible solution, that I can access these files from web application without installing external application. I'm using Apache commons.net library for ftp connection.

Comment: We need [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

There is JSch that is a library to access sftp in Java. I have used it before in a project and is relatively straight forward. Probably you will have to work on it to open files in a web application though.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

Comment: I do not see any mention of SFTP in the question.